# "missing required architecture i386" warning

Tags: ios, ipad, frameworks

In my IOS application external display support is there. So I used libredirect_device.a framework. But I'm getting a warning:

```
ld: warning: in /Volumes/Decelopment/Subversion/Abbott/trunk/development/Source/Abbott/Abbott/ExternalDisplay/libredirect_device.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you'll only get that warning when compiling for simulator. Can you confirm that you're not getting it when compiling for device?

To get rid of the warning I think the library has to be recompiled, so unless you can get a hold of the source or an i386 version you can't get rid of the warning. You could possibly not include it when compiling for simulator.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got my solution. For simulator X-code will use i386 Architecture and for device it will use ARM Architecture. I compiled my code in simulator mode. So its showing warning. If i compile in Device mode, it works fine for me.